# Page animation with loading image

Tags: jquery, html, templates

I have searched a lot on internet. But I can not find a tutorial regarding this type of website. Please review this template and If some one could help explaining this template. i shall be very thankful to him. I just want to know how animation is attached to this. and what code is used to make clean urls. and how they are showing the loading part. And if you come up with something that should be explained then do let me know :)

http://templates.cms-guide.com/51061/  <=== This is the link

Comment: http://templates.cms-guide.com/51061/

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site 
that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once 
the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that 
demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see 
[Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) 
Thanks!